# Test Kendo UI Scheduler with SAPUI5 using mockdata

Tags: sapui5, kendo-scheduler, mockserver

I'm tring to use Telerik KendoUI Scheduler in SAPUI5. I've found this article from SAP community on how to do it:

http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/front-end/blog/2016/01/20/working-with-kendo-ui-controls-in-sapui5

The problem is that for the moment I don't have a backend service, so I need to user mockdata to test it.

I'm tring to use sap mockserver class to simulate the backend service, but I don't understand how to set it and what is the URL for the OData service to call:

```
// Declare the URL for the OData service
var sServiceUrl = "/webapp/localService/mockserver"; --> ??
var pathUrl = "/Room_Set";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to see how you can integrate Kendo UI components to SAPUI5, I think creating a json model might work for you.

```
var oModel = new JSONModel();
var oModel.loadData('data/data.json'); // json file path
this.getView().setModel(oModel);
```

By the way a better option to implement this kind of third party frameworks is to create a custom control. It's better in many ways. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nw8SnXZFqrs

To understand mock server worklist app would be a great place to look at. And also you check this link  https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/3a9728ec31f94ca18a7d543ce419d85d.html.